# "Cannot rollback() inside an XASession" error on Fuse ESB 7.1.0

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix, fuseesb, xa

Yesterday I tried to migrate my bundles from ServiceMix 4.4.1 to Fuse ESB Enterprise 7.1.0. Bundles with local transactions work fine, but other ones with XA transaction don't work well. They write continuously tracebacks with the following messages to the log file:

```
13:30:29,283 | WARN | cation-stageOne] | PooledSession | 139 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-spring - 5.7.0.fuse-71-047 | Caught exception trying rollback() when putting session back into the pool, will invalidate. javax.jms.TransactionInProgressException: Cannot rollback() inside an XASession
javax.jms.TransactionInProgressException: Cannot rollback() inside an XASession
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXASession.rollback(ActiveMQXASession.java:76)279:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.fuse-71-047
at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledSession.close(PooledSession.java:120)139:org.apache.activemq.activemq-spring:5.7.0.fuse-71-047
at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder.closeAll(JmsResourceHolder.java:193)153:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$JmsResourceSynchronization.releaseResource(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:412)153:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$JmsResourceSynchronization.releaseResource(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:1)153:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSynchronization.afterCompletion(ResourceHolderSynchronization.java:98)148:org.springframework.transaction:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:168)148:org.springframework.transaction:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:996)148:org.springframework.transaction:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:971)148:org.springframework.transaction:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:799)148:org.springframework.transaction:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)148:org.springframework.transaction:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.apache.aries.transaction.GeronimoPlatformTransactionManager.commit(GeronimoPlatformTransactionManager.java:76)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25):1.6.0_35
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597):1.6.0_35
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)110:org.springframework.aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
at $Proxy178.commit(Unknown Source)[:]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)153:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)153:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)153:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)153:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886):1.6.0_35
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908):1.6.0_35
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662):1.6.0_35
```

It happens with an empty queue.

My activemq endpoint configuration looks as following:

```
<osgi:reference id="osgiPlatformTransactionManager" interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager"/>
<osgi:reference id="osgiJtaTransactionManager" interface="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jmstx" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsTxConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTxConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiPlatformTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms.concurrentConsumers}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.XaPooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="${jms.maxConnections}" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiJtaTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsXaConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.broker.url}"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="-1"/>
            <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="2000" />
            <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="5000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This endpoint is used very easy in the camel context as:

```
<route id="route">
    <from uri="jmstx:queue:somequeue" />
    <!-- some logic here -->
</route>
```

I would be glad if someone can help me to solve this issue. I can provide more deatails if it necessary.

---

**EDIT**

It seems that the issue is connected to the JMS connection pool: when I change connection factory to a simple ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory, then the exception disappears.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem in the activemq-pool of version 5.7.0 (and most likely earlier versions) and has been reported http://fusesource.com/issues/browse/ENTMQ-441.